# GPUImageStillCamera is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, gpuimage, gpuimagestillcamera

I have a `UIViewController` which has a child hierarchy like this
[image]

and then, I use this code to show camera preview

```
stillCamera = [[GPUImageStillCamera alloc] init];
stillCamera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;

filter = [[GPUImageStretchDistortionFilter alloc] init];
[filter prepareForImageCapture];
[stillCamera addTarget:filter];
GPUImageView *filterview = [[GPUImageView alloc] init];
_preview = filterview;
[filter addTarget:filterview];

[stillCamera startCameraCapture];
```

variable `_preview` is a `UIView` whose class is set to **"GPUImageView"**. On the hierarchy image above, it is the selected one.

When I showed the view, it showed nothing on `_preview`. Just a blank `UIView`. What did I do wrong?

When I changed the line `_preview = filterview` to `self.view = filterview`, it worked as expected. Does it have to be `self.view`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem with your above code is in the lines:

```
GPUImageView *filterview = [[GPUImageView alloc] init];
_preview = filterview;
```

If you've defined your GPUImageView in Interface Builder, `_preview` is going to pointing to a property that you've associated with that view in IB. The above code replaces that pointer with a view that's not the one defined in IB. Therefore, your visible view will never get your camera content.

You need to instead remove those two lines and use

```
[filter addTarget:_preview];
```

making sure that your above setup comes after your view controller has had a chance to properly associate your outlets with your NIB and that the view in IB is indeed a GPUImageView.

Comment: Can't really compete with the master himself @Brad Larson!

Answer (score 1):

You almost have it, try this programmatically first, as I have a very similar situation happening, which is working:

1. Make your camera:

   ```
   stillCamera = [[GPUImageStillCamera alloc] init];
   ```

   stillCamera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
2. Make your preview view:

   `GPUImageView *previewView = [[GPUImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, w, h)];`
3. Make your filter:

   `filter = [[GPUImageStretchDistortionFilter alloc] init];`
4. Now add your filter to your camera:

   `[stillCamera addTarget:filter];`
5. Finally, add your video camera to your previewView:

   `[stillCamera addTarget:previewView];`

EDIT:

Totally goofed! You need to now add the previewView to the actual view! Try this:

```
[self.view addSubview:previewView];
```

Give that a try, GPUImage can be a little confusing at first, but with some tinkering it will work!